# "Connection dispatcher" using MySQL - row-level locking advice?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking, row

I'm thinking about possible ways to quickly solve the issue to which I refer here as "connection dispatching"... and here is the thing.

I have a few (dozens of) servers that can accept a limited number of clients. On the other hand, I have many (thousands of) clients trying to connect to a "free slot" on one of the servers. These sessions are of limited duration, so if a connected client does not disconnect voluntarily, after some time, it will be kicked out forcibly. The following holds true:

- server can report on client-connected/disconnected event
- as mentioned, expired client sessions are forcibly terminated

I thought to do this:
create a two-sided (REST) web service. One side will accept notifications from servers about clients connects/disconnects, while the other side will be used by the clients themselves, querying about the free slot / free server. I thought I'd have one DB table, where each row represents a server and its state, and it could resemble this:

```
 id |  server_ip  |  requests  |  connections  |  max_allowed
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 30.9.50.150 |      5     |       80      |     200
 2  | 30.9.50.151 |     15     |      130      |     200
```

What I obviously need is a consistent (synchronized) way to do SELECTs/UPDATEs on both sides of this service, since both notifications and client queries may happen simultaneously. I'll give an example of possible (pseudo) SQL queries, i.e. the transactions:

**server notification side:**

```
SELECT requests as curr_reqs, connections as curr_conns
FROM server WHERE id = server_id;

-- if client-connect occurred:
UPDATE server SET connections = (curr_conns + 1), requests = (curr_reqs - 1)
WHERE id = server_id;

-- if client-disconnect occurred:
UPDATE server SET connections = (curr_conns - 1)
WHERE id = server_id;
```

**client query side:**

```
SELECT id as free_id, requests as curr_reqs, server_ip as free_ip FROM server
WHERE connections < (0.6 * max_allowed) AND
requests < max_allowed
ORDER BY requests DESC;

-- if a free record is obtained:
UPDATE server SET requests = (curr_reqs + 1)
WHERE id = free_id;
```

.
So, I read a bit about MySQL locking modes and stuff (e.g. [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)), but I'm not quite able to decide what is the thing I need in this scenario, to maintain consistent data per server (table row). Can someone give an advice about appropriate locking mode / transaction layout?

Comment: There are lots of load-balancing products and services on the market. With respect, it's easier to reinvent the flat tire than it is to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Plain load balancer won't work here, because we're talking about VPN servers (pretty limited number), and the number of clients can be huge, so beside just doing the load balancing, this stuff needs to be slightly more intelligent, and notify the clients about the status